# Identifying elements css

Tags: css, css-selectors, squarespace

long time reader, first time poster.

I've created a site using Squarespace. I have a question about selecting specific elements on a page.

On a page that has multiple images, I'm trying to apply a hover on just 1 of the images. But I'm having trouble selecting just 1 image. The custom CSS code that I'm using currently applys the hover across all images on that page:

```css
.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 .sqs-block-image {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 .sqs-block-image:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #2098d1;
  height: 4px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4px);
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 .sqs-block-image:hover:before, .sqs-block-image:focus:before, .sqs-block-image:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795713/4774292 saying that "Id-selector. Useful when you want to apply styling to a single specific element."

My question is: how do I find the Id of individual images on a page to create a custom css on? I feel like this is made more difficult when using Squarespace or other website developing platforms like it. Any help would be awesome. (I should have studied this in college instead of an arts degree. *sigh)

Comment: _“how do I find the Id of individual images on a page to create a custom css on?”_ – simplest way: By using your browser’s developer tools to inspect the image element, and see what id it has set (if any).

Comment: Hey CBroe, thanks for the comment. The 'Inspect Element' gives me a dynamic Id (not static). It changes each time the page reloads. Maybe I'm doing this wrong? It's #yui_3_17_2_1_1428676528939_530 Keeps changing though.

Comment: Well if Squarespace doesn’t _give_ you a static id, but creates a different one every time the page is rendered, that means you can’t use that id, and have to find another way to select that specific image element (f.e. based on it’s position in the DOM tree, inside another element that has a static id, or a certain element name and is the n-th of its type, or or or … there are a lot of possibilities, but without knowing the actual HTML [and which parts of it will stay “static”], no one here can say what might work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem. Thank you to everyone who provided answers, they definitely helped. Here's how I resolved, and if later it turns out this doesn't work for whatever reason I'll update. As of now this works:

Viewed source. Searched "block-". Found the block ID of the specific element I wanted to select (it was an image). Here's what the coding around it looked like:

```
</div>
</div></div></div></div><div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image" data-block-type="5" id="block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999"><div class="sqs-block-content">
<div class="image-block-outer-wrapper layout-caption-below ">

    <div class="intrinsic" style="max-width:2500.0px;">

            <div style="padding-bottom:75.0%;" class="image-block-wrapper   has-aspect-ratio" data-description="">
                <noscript><img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53c54097e4b009a27bdeec79/t/5527d477e4b079f2c38cc94b/1428673662307/group"  alt="group"  /></noscript><img class="thumb-image" alt="group" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53c54097e4b009a27bdeec79/t/5527d477e4b079f2c38cc94b/1428673662307/group" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53c54097e4b009a27bdeec79/t/5527d477e4b079f2c38cc94b/1428673662307/group" data-image-dimensions="2500x1875" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-id="5527d477e4b079f2c38cc94b" data-type="image" />
            </div>
```

Block ID here is:

```
block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999
```

So I inserted this code in the Page Header:

```
<style> #block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
-o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
-ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
transition: all 300ms ease-out; }

#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999 {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
background: #2098d1;
height: 4px;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-4px);
transform: translateY(-4px);
-webkit-transition-property: transform;
transition-property: transform;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999:hover:before, 
#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999:focus:before, 
#block-yui_3_17_2_2_1428673541254_8999:active:before {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
}
</style>
```

My final result: http://www.p2sk.ca/testing-grounds Notice how the group photo image block has the style affect I want (fade + blue line appearing on hover), and not the other images. (I'm sorry for the obnoxiously large Toronto Maple Leafs picture).

The difference between a yui element and a block-yui element in Squarespace is that (as far as I can tell, do correct me if I'm wrong) the block-yui element doesn't change. It's static. So your CSS will remain. Got that part from this post: http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/50607/custom-css-div-id

I tested the page by: 1) refreshing constantly 2) closing the browser and reopening 3) moving the selected image block to a different part of the page 4) all the above in different combinations.

The block-yui ID didn't change. The desired effect remained. *wipes sweat

Cheers,

(PS. I'll wait until someone confirms this before tagging it as the final answer to this post.)

Answer (score 6):

What you are using now is called a class selector and what you need to do is use id-selector as mentioned on the post.

Thing of class as a category and think of id as an individual within the category.

> but isn't Id-selector HTML

ID selector is CSS concept while ids are an HTML concept. HTML is for describing your document and CSS is for styling your document based on the description. So id, calss are descriptions and selecting those ids is how you add styles with CSS.

That's just some theoretical information. Let me now show you how to do id-selection in your particualr case.

This is what you have:

```
.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 .sqs-block-image {
   ...
 }

.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 .sqs-block-image:before {
  ...
}

.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 .sqs-block-image:hover:before, .sqs-block-image:focus:before, .sqs-block-image:active:before 
{
  ... 
}
```

This is how you select it based on IDs

```
.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 #sqs-block-image {
   ...
 }

.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 #sqs-block-image:before {
  ...
}

.collection-54d92b4ee4b0661469eb9a15 #sqs-block-image:hover:before, #sqs-block-image:focus:before, #sqs-block-image:active:before 
{
  ... 
}
```

'#' is how you select elements based on their ID.

Then you also need to go to the HTML element and change its ID to be sqs-block-image or anything else that you would like.

I would actually recommend choosing another name - more specific because this name is general for all images so you don't want to mess with that.

Instead add a separate id and then select it with #.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I unfortunately either cannot or don't know how to change the Id name of elements. The .sqs-block-image selects all image blocks on a page. When using 'Inspect Element' the images give a dynamic Id (not static). Having trouble find the static Id for these elements on squarespace. [p2sk](http://www.p2sk.ca/testing-grounds) here's where I test things out. See the 3 images? Can't seem to identify each images unique and static Id.

Comment: This is exactly what you are asking check it out: http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/23786/why-does-an-objects-id-change-on-page-refresh

Comment: I would actually say instead of using ids use different classes so instead of saying .sqs-block-image use a different name .specific_image_I_am_trying_to_target it's not the best practice out there but since they are not giving you a chance to have static ids you have to have a way around it. They are doing it for better performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of posting on SO!

You are totally right that Id's belong to HTML elements. One of the cool thing about CSS is that it can talk to the HTML using these ID's, and classes actually too (And other things, but don't worry about that for now).

CSS selects particular html elements using selectors. You can apply stylings to those selectors. To select by id you prepend a #.

For example,

```
<div id="doggie">Dog</div>
```

can be selected with `#doggie` in css. Thus

```
#doggie {
  color: red;
}
```

will apply red font to the text in the element with id `doggie`.

Applying styling to html that you can't control is a little more tricky. To find out what id squarespace is giving an element (in chrome) you should right click the thing you want to change and select `Inspect Element`. It should pop up the html for the page with that element selected. By looking at that element's html you should be able to figure out how to select it in CSS.

It's important that the identifier you use is static. If squarespace changes the id or class every time the page is loaded, the css won't continue to work.

More reading on css selectors: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/
A codeacademy: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-XUclI/0/1

Comment: That's fantastic. Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately when using 'Inspect Element' on an image, I get: #yui_3_17_2_1_1428676528939_530. This changes each time the page loads. It seems to me the closest static element is .sqs-block-image but I feel like I'm missing something. [p2sk](http://www.p2sk.ca/testing-grounds) This is where I test things out. 

ps. thanks for the links, I'll be sure to go through the code academy course.

Comment: so if the id's change every time, you'll have to get a little creative/hacky with the selectors. 

looking at that page you sent it looks like the image has an attribute called data-image-id="<somethingsomething>"

you can select via that if that somethingsomething doesnt change. to select by attribute in css you want to do [data-image-id="5527d477e4b079f2c38cc94b"], or whatever the image id is and then apply classes to that

Comment: I would suggest instead using nested selectors starting with the selector you know is static and getting more specific from there  http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/grouping/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the inspect element, but you need to specificly do so on the image you want to alter and target either the data-image or the data-image-id. Those should be static. I don't remember off the top of my head which targets the image and which targets the content, but one of those should be correct.